# Query the last instance with condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails application how can I query the last instance of a particular model having multiple conditions?

```
class User
    has_many: tests

class TestAttempt
    belongs_to: user
    belongs_to: test

class Test
    has_many: test_attempts
```

The problem here is each user can take a single test any number of times. Each test_attempt is stored in `TestAttempt`. But I need to query only the last attempt of a particular test. So the process is like this:

```
Find TestAttempt by user_id ---> Something like this ---> TestAttempt.where(user_id: user_id)
Then find the test_id's of the above query.
Then get the last instance of the TestAttempt for each Test for each User
```

So my output might be something like:

```
user1: test_1-last-attempt-marks: 28, test_2-last-attempt-marks-30
user2: test_1-last-attempt-marks: 18, test_2-last-attempt-marks-40
```

Right now I am querying the database and adding the results to the array for a particular user and then looping over each element of the array and taking the last instance of the value like this:

```
def get_test_marks(user_id)
    tests = Test.where(user_id: user_id).to_a
    tests.each do |test|
        #check the name and and add to array if not present, if present then delete the existing one and add new one until last for each test        
    end
```

**Or**

```
def get_test_marks(user_id)
    test_attempts = TestAttempt.where(user_id: user_id).select('distinct test_id, marks')
```

Is there a way to query directly from database the last attempt of each test for a particular user instead of writing code in the above way?

Comment: Try this **Test.where(user_id: user_id).order(created_at: :asc).last(1)**. If not worked let me know.

Comment: Here I will get only for one test. What I want is the last results of unique tests like test1, test2, test3 and so on for each user. For eg: `User1 might have taken test1-2 times, test2-3 times and test3-4 times`. So I want `2nd instance of test1, 3rd instance of test2, 4th instance of test3 for user1 and so on for other users`.

Comment: **Test.where(user_id: user_id).group_by {|test| test.testname }.flat_map { |test,data| data.sort_by(&:created_at).last(1)
} **   
**NOTE:** Instead of testname you can replace with which column you want to group in data. I hope this will work.

Comment: I have added more details to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Test.all.group_by { |test|  
test.user_id}.flat_map { |test, data|  data.sort_by(&:created_at).last(1)
}
```

Try this updated code